# Serialize and Deserialize a static member in a class?

Tags: c#, serialization, dictionary

I've encountered a problem in my simple project. I want to build a bookstore manager that keeps track of books that go in store (on a bill, from a supplier) and books that leave the store when I sell them. In order to keep track of books I store them in a dictionary with the **key** being the book's ISBN. It looks like this:

```
Dictionary<string,IBook> BOOKS;
```

In addition I need another dictionary that keeps track of bills from different suppliers.
That one looks like this:

```
Dictionary<string,Supplier> SUPPLIERS;
```

The **key** in this case is the supplier name.
Each supplier has a list of bills as a data field:

```
[Serializable]
public class Supplier
{
    private List<Bill>  supplierBills;
    private string      supplierName;
    ....
}
```

Now each Bill looks like this:

```
[Serializable] 
public class Bill 
{
    private List<IBook> billBooksList;
    private double      billTotalDue;
    private DateTime    billCreationDate;
    private DateTime    billDueDate;

    public static int   billNumber = 0;
}
```

When I close the application I **serialize** both the BOOKS dictionary and the SUPPLIERS dictionary. When I open it, **deserialization** takes place. My problem is related to the static member **billNumber** from the Bill class. It won't serialize. Every time I open the application the variable resets to 0.

I tried to use the example from [how to serialize and deserialize static member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220759/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-static-member) but I don't serialize a static member from the immediate class (in my case is the Supplier class).

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Use a real database instead.

Comment: Why is billNumber static? Why do you need to Serialize it?

Comment: I use billNumber static so that when I add a new Bill I can differentiate between them. I need to serialize it because when I close the app the value would be lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`billNumber` shouldn't be `static`. `lastBillNumber` can be `static`. I don't think that all your bills can share the same `billNumber` :-)

Now... Lets say you have to save the `lastBillNumber` (so that your next bill can be `lastBillNumber+1`. The right place to do it is to have a singleton class

```
class BillNumberGenerator
{
    protected int LastBillNumber;

    public GetNewBillNumber()
    {
        LastBillNumber++;
        return LastBillNumber;
    }
}

static BillNumberGenerator MyBillNumberGenerator = new BillNumberGenerator();
```

and then you serialize it. So you have to serialize `Supplier`, `Bill`, `BillNumberGenerator`.

Comment: What do you mean by "billNumber isn't static" ?

Comment: @AlinArgintaru Changed the phrasing. If `billNumber` is static, then all your bills have the same `billNumber`.

Comment: Oh God...How could I miss that? Thanks for your answer !